# How to check and uncheck dynamic checkbox in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Below is my Code

```
{
  allSymptoms &&
    allSymptoms.map((val, idx) => {
      return (
        <Row>
          <Text>{val.name}</Text>
          <Switch value={val.name} key={idx} onChange={() => toggleSwitch()} />
        </Row>
      );
    });
}

function toggleSwitch() {
  //I am stuck here
}
```

Comment: Is allSymptoms array in your component's state?

Comment: Yes. 
 const [allSymptoms, setAllSymptoms] = useState([]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your state every time you change the value of one of the Switches. Update your code as follows

```
{allSymptoms.map((item, idx) => (
  <Row key={idx}>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    <Switch
      onValueChange={value => toggleSwitch(value, idx)}
      value={item.isEnabled}
    />
  <Row>
))}


const toggleSwitch = (value, index) => {
  if (allSymptoms[index].isEnabled === value) return;

  const symptoms = allSymptoms.map((item, idx) => {
    let { isEnabled } = item;
    if (index === idx) {
      isEnabled = value;
    }
    return { ...item, isEnabled };
  });
  setAllSymptoms(symptoms);
};
```

If you want to add interaction to the Text try following

```
{allSymptoms.map((item, idx) => (
  <Row key={idx}>
    <Text onPress={() => {
        toggleSwitch(!item.isEnabled, idx);
      }}
      >
        {item.name}
    </Text>
    <Switch
      onValueChange={value => toggleSwitch(value, idx)}
      value={item.isEnabled}
    />
  <Row>
))}
```

Comment: your solution worked perfectly and I owe a lot of thanks. However My client wants the switch to on and off on clicking its text. If you can help me please.

Comment: @NgawangZepa Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem? I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Your above answers is partially working. It worked to on the switch but not able to off at the same time. Any idea? Do share please

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution has worked. If you have little time please write to me at nzepa.ttpl@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
 allSymptoms &&
  allSymptoms.map((val, idx) => {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Text>{val.name}</Text>
        <Switch
          trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
          thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
          ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
          onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch(idx)}
          value={val.isEnabled} />
      </Row>
    );
  });

toggleSwitch = function (index) {
  allSymptoms.map((val, idx) => {
    if (index === idx) {
      val.isEnabled = true
    } else {
      val.isEnabled = false
    }
  })
}
```

Note: I have used this [Switch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch)

Comment: Thank you @Rajan for your ans. It doesn't seem to work in my project. Could you please explain me what is isEnabled  is? is that field name fetch from API? or component variable?

Comment: It just a variable i have used to store whether switch is on or off.

Comment: @Rojan. Can you help me with another solution please? I honestly Thank You for the above solution but it isn't working. If there is another please share.

Comment: You need to store that switch is on or off. In same array or in another array. If you liked my this answer and you fill it will help others. I would suggest to upvote it so others can get to see it in search.